# Return path to rubygems.rb

Tags: ruby, file-system, modules

From the command line, I can easily find the path to `rubygems.rb`

```
$ gem which rubygems
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb
```

and from a Ruby script I can also do this

```
require 'rubygems/commands/which_command'
wc = Gem::Commands::WhichCommand.new
puts wc.find_paths 'rubygems', $LOAD_PATH
```

However is a simpler way available to do this, for example without using
`require 'rubygems/commands/which_command'`, and without a `system()` call?

Update from posted answer

```
puts $".grep(/rubygems.rb/).first
```

Update from posted comment

```
puts Gem.method(:dir).source_location.first
```

Comment: Don't you think this question should go on SO?

Comment: Sounds strange... I agree the answer is excellent, it is just a pity (IMHO) that it is not on SO... I think that people will look for similar things there, not here...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/660129

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether a simpler solution exists depends on what your motivation is.

Let's look inside the implementation of `Gem::Commands::WhichCommand#find_paths`.

```
  def find_paths(package_name, dirs)
    result = []

    dirs.each do |dir|
      Gem.suffixes.each do |ext|
        full_path = File.join dir, "#{package_name}#{ext}"
        if File.exist? full_path and not File.directory? full_path then
          result << full_path
          return result unless options[:show_all]
        end
      end
    end

    result
  end
```

That's the code you need.  If there were a simpler way, `find_paths` would have used it.

*However,* there is a way to cheat: [`Kernel#require`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require) needs to do a very similar thing when it actually tries to load a module:

> #### require(name) → true or false
>
> Loads the given `name`, returning `true` if successful and `false` if
>   the feature is already loaded.
>
> If the filename does not resolve to an absolute path, it will be
>   searched for in the directories listed in `$LOAD_PATH` (`$:`).
>
> If the filename has the extension “.rb”, it is loaded as a source
>   file; if the extension is “.so”, “.o”, or “.dll”, or the default
>   shared library extension on the current platform, Ruby loads the
>   shared library as a Ruby extension. Otherwise, Ruby tries adding
>   “.rb”, “.so”, and so on to the name until found. If the file named
>   cannot be found, a `LoadError` will be raised.
>
> For Ruby extensions the filename given may use any shared library
>   extension. For example, on Linux the socket extension is “socket.so”
>   and `require 'socket.dll'` will load the socket extension.
>
> The absolute path of the loaded file is added to `$LOADED_FEATURES`
>   (`$"`). A file will not be loaded again if its path already appears in
>   `$"`. For example, `require 'a'; require './a'` will not load `a.rb`
>   again.

Or, it might be more accurate to say that `find_paths` simulates what `require` would do.

Therefore, if you are willing to let Ruby actually load the file first, then you could ask Ruby after the fact:

```
require 'rubygems'
$LOADED_FEATURES.grep /\/rubygems\./
```